# Inheritance in Kotlin

Tags: oop, inheritance, kotlin

Trying to figure out with Kotlin last days, have read the doc and found one example. In the bottom of the [article](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html):

```
interface A {
    fun foo() { print("A") }
    fun bar()
}

interface B {
    fun foo() { print("B") }
    fun bar() { print("bar") }
}

class C : A {
    override fun bar() { print("bar") }
}

class D : A, B {
    override fun foo() {
        super<A>.foo()
        super<B>.foo()
    }
}
```

> Now, if we derive a concrete class C from A, we, obviously, have to override bar() and provide an implementation. And if we derive D from A and B, **we don’t have to override bar()**, because we have inherited only one implementation of it.

I've tried to do that, but IDE underlines that I must override bar() function from A class, because D class inherits multiple interface methods of bar()

**Update: [Kotlin issue-tracker.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14797#comment=27-1720286)**

Comment: What question are you asking?

Comment: @AndrewOrobator, Is it mistake in the article or I'm doing smth wrong?

Comment: Seems there is an error in the article. See my answer below

Comment: @AndrewOrobator, I've seen, thanks for answer, I hope other developers will see it

Comment: You should file this as an issue in http://kotl.in/issue because the compiler disagrees with the official documentation.  And since you can't fight the compiler (and it will be slower to be changed) it is best to go find out which one must change in a way that can be tracked or acted upon by the team.  Obviously there is a conflict here that needs resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an error with the article. Because `D` inherits from `A` and `B`, interfaces which both have the `bar()` method, both implementations must be defined.

Comment: No way. In Kotlin methods in interfaces behave should the same as default methods in Java8. There isn't any docs that says otherwise. I think it's a compiler bug, but someone'll tell from the Kotlin team.